# Finding real-numbers subsets which are isomorphic to some ordinals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

For example I know that $A=\{5-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\cup\{6,7,8,...,k+6\}$ is isomorphic to $\omega + k$ for $k<\omega\;$ because I know I can look at  $\omega + k\;$ as $\; B=(n\times\{0\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cup(j\times\{1\})_{6\leq j\leq k+6} $ with the lexicograpic order.

However, If I wanted to find real numbers subset which is isomorphic to $\omega + \omega + k\;$ for $k<\omega\;$

How could I do that? how can I visualize this ordinal in order to give it a mataching real subset.

As well as for $\omega + \omega + \omega + ... + \omega$ (n times)

I would love to get some examples and intuition if possible! thanks.

Comment: For $\omega+\omega+k$ you have $$\left\{1-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\{1\}\cup\left\{2-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\{2,3,\ldots,2+k-1\}$$ if $k>0$.

Comment: So for $\omega + \omega + \omega + ... + \omega$ I just need to take $n$ copies of those?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Also, how could I describe those as I described $\omega + k\;$ as $\; B=(n\times\{0\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cup(j\times\{1\})_{6\leq j\leq k+6}$ with the lexographic order? 
I just need to add more lines across the Y axis?

Comment: With that set $B$ you’d need the reverse lexicographic order, with $\langle m,i\rangle\preceq\langle n,j\rangle$ iff $i<j$, or $i=j$ and $m\le n$, in order to get something order-isomorphic to $\omega+k$.

Comment: As A is a finite set, it cannot be order isomorphic to an infinite ordinal,

Comment: @WilliamElliot it is infinite, i forgot to mention it holds for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: That not what you wrote.  Edit your post so it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, then there is an injective map $f:\alpha\to\omega$, and
$$\xi\mapsto\sum_{\eta\lt\xi}2^{-f(\eta)}$$
is an order embedding of $\alpha$ into $\mathbb R$.

A similar argument shows that every countable linear order is embeddable in $\mathbb R$. A different argument is needed if you want to show that every countable linear order is embeddable in $\mathbb Q$, or that every countable ordinal is order-isomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That's a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

{ k + n : k + 1 - 1/n : n,k in N, n /= 0 }
is order isomorphic to $\omega_0$ ×  $\omega_0$.